How would I translate If I cannot bend the will of hell, I shall move heaven
I want to translate this quote but the reverse. The quote is “If I cannot bend the will of heaven, I shall move hell” in Latin, Flectere si nequeo superos, Acheronta movebo, by Virgil, a Roman.
How would I write “If I cannot bend the will of hell, I shall move heaven.”

Funny enough, all you have to do is transpose superos and Acheronta. Both are accusative (direct objects of their respective verbs), so no further changes are necessary.
You have myriad options for choosing words for "heaven" and "hell", but I'd choose none of them, lest the reference and meter are lost.
So:

Flectere si nequeo Acheronta, superos movebo.

